# Seeded Pseudo Random Number Generator

Tags: random, numbers, random-seed, noise-generator

I am developing a Perlin Noise generator which works based on a seed integer and on two other integers: x and y.

By now, the pseudo-random number generator is looking like this:

```
private float noise(int x, int y) {     

    int n = x + y * seed;
    return (1.0f - ((n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824f);

}
```

But there are some problems with this implementation: first of all, the return interval is not constant (ideally, I would like to work with [-1, 1] or [0, 1]) and for negative x and y values, the pattern gets blocky, not looking organic at all.
Is there a way to change my formula (or maybe a totally new one) which would make it fit my needs?

Comment: Please give some more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need a pseudorandom number generator which works based on 3 seeds (the actual seed, x and y, which are all integers), generating floats from -1 to 1 and which also works when negative input is given.

Comment: is this JAVA? looks like it.

Comment: It is java, sorry for not saying it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use this one (i found it on the net, but i don't have the original link anymore):

```
private double noise(int x, int y) {
    int n=(int)x*331+(int)y*337; // add your seed on this line.
    n=(n<<13)^n;
    int nn=(n*(n*n*41333 +53307781)+1376312589)&0x7fffffff;       
    return ((1.0-((double)nn/1073741824.0))+1)/2.0;

}
```

You can easy add your seed to it.

Comment: Thank you! The output generated by this function is looking really nice. The only problem I still have is when I give negative coordinates in, which gives a blocky pattern. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it would make the noise axis-symmetrical, which is not my goal. There should be another way to achieve it.

Comment: If you know how far you go negative, you can use that as an offset just add the offset to all values, like this your max negative will become 0.

Comment: I get the idea, but I want to achieve "infinite" (as big as an int) noise.